# Im trying to create user interface for bellman-ford algorithm because i cant find it anywhere

Tags: forms, visual-studio, user-interface, c++-cli, visual-studio-2019

It doesn't show me any errors, it just doesn't show result in the labels I want it to.
I have to add that I'm new with coding and I'm just starting to learn.
Basically I want to take values from textBoxes typed in by user in form then use them in function, then display results using labels.

[image]

Also: why does command prompt also show up when I run it?

Here is the code:

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#define MAX 10

namespace Project1 {
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    typedef struct edge
    {
        int src;
        int dest;
        int wt;
    }edge;

    void bellman_ford(int *nv, edge e[], int *src_graph, int *ne) {
        int u, v, weight, i, j = 0;
        int dis[MAX];
        int d1, d2, d3, d4 = 0;
        int* es1, * es2, * es3, * es3, * es4;
        int* ed1, * ed2, * ed3, * ed3, * ed4;
        int* wt1, * wt2, * wt3, * wt3, * wt4;

        for (i = 0; i <= *nv; i++)
        {
            dis[i] = 999;
        }

        /* distanta de la nodul sursa la el insusi este 0 */
        dis[*src_graph] = 0;
        //src
        e[0].src = *es1;
        e[1].src = *es2;
        e[2].src = *es3;
        e[3].src = *es4;
        //dest
        e[0].dest = *ed1;
        e[1].dest = *ed2;
        e[2].dest = *ed3;
        e[3].dest = *ed4;
        //wt
        e[0].wt = *wt1;
        e[1].wt = *wt2;
        e[2].wt = *wt3;
        e[3].wt = *wt4;

        for (i = 0; i < *nv - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < *ne; j++)
            {
                u = e[j].src;
                v = e[j].dest;
                weight = e[j].wt; 
                if (dis[u] != 999 && dis[u] + weight < dis[v]) 
                {
                 dis[v] = dis[u] + weight;
                }
            }
        }
        for (j = 0; j < *ne; j++)
        {
            u = e[j].src;
            v = e[j].dest;
            weight = e[j].wt;

            if (dis[u] + weight < dis[v])
            {
                char eroare[] = "There is a negative cycle!!!";
                return;
            }
        }

        d1 = dis[0];
        d2 = dis[1];
        d3 = dis[2];
        d4 = dis[3];
    }

    int main()
    {
        int *nv, *ne, *src_graph;
        edge e[MAX];

        bellman_ford(nv, e, src_graph, ne);

        return 0;
    }
....

#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    }
    //input
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        //
        int nv = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox1->Text);
        int ne = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox2->Text);
        int src_graph = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox3->Text);
        //m1
        int es1 = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox4->Text);
        int ed1 = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox5->Text);
        int wt1 = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox6->Text);
        //m2
        int es2 = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox9->Text);
        int ed2 = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox8->Text);
        int wt2 = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox7->Text);
        //m3
        int es3 = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox15->Text);
        int ed3 = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox14->Text);
        int wt3 = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox13->Text);
        //m4
        int es4 = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox12->Text);
        int ed4 = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox11->Text);
        int wt4 = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox10->Text);
    }

    //output
    private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        int* d1;
        int* d2;
        int* d3;
        int* d4;

        label27->Text = System::Convert::ToString(*d1);
        label28->Text = System::Convert::ToString(*d2);
        label29->Text = System::Convert::ToString(*d3);
        label30->Text = System::Convert::ToString(*d4);
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated: `typedef struct edge { ... } edge;` can be made into `struct edge { ... };` - The `typedef` is automatic for classes in C++ and a `struct` is a class.

Comment: You'll be lucky if anyone can find the error by just looking at that amount of code without the possibility to compile it.. I think you'll need to create a [mcve].

Comment: This looks like `C++/CLI` since `String^` is a syntax error in standard C++.